# HTML: Internal links only work into directories but not out?

Tags: html, macos, hyperlink

I have been getting to grips with html for the past two days. I understand how internal links work perfectly fine. The problem is getting the path to correctly redirect to the main page. The reason I ask, is I have looked all over and it's implicitly stated that "../index.html" (specifically the '../') will look to the previous folder.

It keeps telling me file not found. I even tried using the complete root path and it still won't work. Maybe this is slightly different on Mac? As I also can't get my .jpg files to show properly. My image files are located in the same folder as index.html.

Mac OS X 10.9.5

EDIT: Something strange, look at what the file path is showing in the browser.
[file path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeUWc.png)

Comment: Just  a tip, when you're using something like brackets or notepad++(i think), it autocompletes the path for you, be it images, folders, anything.See if that helps?

Comment: Also, to redirect to the main page even href="/" should work.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck just using Text Edit right now. It seems to work fine with formatting turned off though. Well, darn thanks for the tips. I wish it was that simple but "/" didn't work either.

Comment: I'm slightly confused as to what exactly the problem is.You're trying to get have a click on a link redirect to the index page, correct?And Something like "/" isn't working?

Comment: Yes. I have a home page index.html, and in the same folder is a folder 'pages' with two more .html files. I have linked to those two from the main page's table of contents, but the link to return to the main page won't find the index.html file.

Comment: I updated my post with a picture. According to that it seems I just can't back out of the pages folder. I don't understand why you can't just have all the .html files in one location?